# Add captcha to my RStudio Server login page

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I installed RStudio Server on a Digital Ocean Droplet. Unfortunately I get abuse reports about Brute-force activities on a regular basis. In order to prevent this I'd like to add a **captcha** to my **RStudio login page** (where I log in, in order to open RStudio). Is there any way to realize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After long search I did not manage to install a captcha. However I managaed to control the attacks by installing Fail2Ban on my server. Other possibilities, see [this blog post](https://webdevstudios.com/2015/03/10/dealing-with-brute-force-attacks-by-yourself/).